# Force data sync with firebase server from Android

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, android-sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an Android app which has sqlite database. I wanted to add synchronisation for the db with some cloud service and across multiple devices of the same user. There will be login mechanism and data will be different for different users. The synchronisation will be for logged in users only. For others the data will reside locally only.

I found firebase very interesting and started adding it for the synchronisation. I cannot completely replace sqlite with firebase because I need to provide offline experience for users that are not logged in.

I implemented syncadapter for the sync operation. And I'm doing the sqlite<->firebase two way synchronisation there.

I'm using firebase transactions to avoid conflict from multiple devices. But I read that firebase Android initially writes on offline database and sync with server at a later time. This may cause transactions to fail sometimes creating inconsistencies in data. And also I think transactions are not maintained across app restarts.

If there was an option to disable offline feature for firebase and each request is sent to server instantly and finish with a successful completion or a failure I may be able to implement the synchronisation correctly here.

So is there any way to force to do write and read directly to and from server?
Is there a better way to do this ensuring good conflict handling across multiple devices?
Is firebase not suited for this purpose?

Comment: Too much text, not enough code. But a few things: "I need to provide offline experience for users that are not logged in". Firebase does not require the users to be logged in. If you're worried about identifying the users, you can use [anonymous authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/anonymous.html).

Comment: "is there any way to force to do write and read directly to and from server?". [Detect if the user is connected to Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state), and only then write.

Comment: "If there was an option to disable offline feature for firebase and each request is sent to server instantly and finish with a successful completion or a failure" Sounds like you're looking for a [completion listener](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-update#section-completion-callback).

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your comments. Sorry for the long text. I didn't add code because I'm seeking solution to my design issues.

Will anonymous authentication work offline? Can I ensure all data for the anonymous user be available offline (just like sqlite) irrespective of whether the user connected to network or not. I think there is limit on amount of data that can be persisted offline in firebase.

Comment: Even if I check connected status and do the write, is it guaranteed that the connection persists till the operation is finished? Basically I don't want the data to saved offline (while using sqlite + firebase) it should either write to the server or fail and get callback on this so that I can keep track of it.

If a complete listener is invoked with no FirebaseError can I assume the data is written to the server by that time? Will it fail if there is no connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for the solution.

**While using firebaseRef.addValueEventListener() initially it loads data from available cache, then requests updated data from server.**

In order to retrieve latest server side data, We made sure user is connected to internet and also connected to firebase server database.

```
        DatabaseReference connectionRefrence;
        ValueEventListener connectionValueEventListener;

        connectionRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
        connectionValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connected) {
                    printLog("connected");
                    // TODO :: Perform your operation here with live data

                } else {
                    printLog("not connected");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                printLog("connection cancelled");

            }
        };
```

I hope it helps.